# how to create stack using linkedlist and complexity of its functions in java

Tags: java

how to create stack using Linked List and complexity of its functions in java. I have tried but used exceptions and all from jdk. is there any code from scratch. own exceptions. flow diagram to understand it easily

Comment: please explain your case more precisely. and add your current failing code and exception logs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A nice explanation is given on [enter link description here](http://www.diaryreaders.com/implementation-of-stack-using-linkedlist/)

on this page, they are using their own exception and mentioned the runtime complexity. I think that really helps and can solve your problem

Great job.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. Thank you. great

Comment: please add actual code example, so that future users can get answer even if the link is expired.

Comment: I am not able to copy the code from the page http://www.diaryreaders.com/implementation-of-stack-using-linkedlist/ . may be we have to comment here to allow copy the code from the page. getting late. I leave this task to comment and get the copy of the code from the page on some one else. Thank you.